Can one be immortal then not immortal?
A friend and I are having a discussion about immortality. I believe that if someone claims to be immortal, then they die then they were never immortal to begin with. My friend believes that it would be possible to be immortal then lose that immortality, and maintains that the person was indeed immortal for a time.

A person can be immortal until they fight an enemy with immortality-piercing attacks.

This sounds a bit more like a question about the definition of the word "immortal" than a philisophical one... May be better asked at english.SE? But a quick look on dictionary.com suggests that it could go either way! "not liable or subject to death; undying:" - which could be considered a temporary state, but also "imperishable; everlasting." which would be more permanent

I'm not dead yet, am I temporarily immortal?

Being mortal means you will die. Negating doesn't have to mean that you won't die. It could mean that might live forever, if you don't get hit by a bus. The concept of mortality is tied to the repeated demonstration that people have limited life spans. The essential problem is any idiot can claim it wont happen to them. You can't prove them wrong until their gone. This concept isn't something that emerges from an individual. It's something you observe about a group over time. You might think rocks are immortal. But maybe you just haven't been around long enough to see how they die.

https://youtu.be/l-yVqmL5j5w?t=78

There is a difference between truly immortal and just everlasting, but in practice people often use "immortal" ambiguously for both. Someone everlasting has no natural expiration date and can last forever unless killed or compromised in some milder way that takes away their longevity (like pop-cultural vampires). Your friend is referring to this meaning. On the other hand, someone truly immortal cannot be killed or compromised in any way that leads to death (like Christian God). So for this meaning your conclusion is correct, if someone dies they were never truly immortal to begin with.

I guess it depends on if we interpret "immortal" as a state or as an intrinsic property of a person.
Take Super Mario Bros. - When you get the star, you are temporarily invincible. During that time, Mario is immortal (they cannot die).
Contrast that with a Greek god like Zeus - he cannot be mortal, ever.
Another example is "warm" -- a person with a fever is warm temporarily whereas a star is warm intrinsically -- it ceases to exist as a star if it is not warm.
So, I think you are both right but you are using "immortal" in different senses.

Am I right then in thinking I've been immortal so far?

@Philomath - have you ever survived what should be lethal? If not then prior evidence says no - people are capable of being killed at any moment. Nothing says we are guaranteed to know when we are immortal.

If I can have a fever and be warm temporarily, why can't I be immortal temporarily? You said they were both right...(upvoted your answer, but I am not sure about the temporal aspect..)

@Philomath you can — I was distinguishing between constitutive and non-constitutive immortality

I feel like you're conflating "immortal" and "invincible" in this answer. Invincibility typically implies immunity to physical damage, not time. (Also, invincible Mario still dies if he falls down a pit :P) Immortality to my mind implies both invincibility and some deeper property; that the ending of the being is a true impossibility in any fashion.

@ConnieMnemonic For what we knows so far, nothing is immortal (in any sense of the word) in the real world. So one have to take into context that 'immortality' has always been tied to stories or myth and can thus be defined diferently depending on the media. Sometimes immortal is unaging, sometimes it's being blade proof, sometimes it's being a god... etc. So I agree with Annika that it's just about how you want to define it.

@ConnieMnemonic lol -- I thought of that with Mario not being immune from pits ;-) But I think the broader thing I was getting at is that immortality can be thought of as constitutive (your view) or non-constitutive (mario bros example). The properties that define an  immortal at any moment can apply forever or for a tempoary time.

Third option: "immortal" is a prediction, that someone will never die at any point in the future.

@kaya3 +1 didn’t think of that perspective :)

Lets compare with other words and their usual meaning.
Impenetrable:
Can not be penetrated. So a impenetrable defense should not be able to get... well penetrated. But in real life we do observe the usage of "impenetrable" even though with enough force/the right tools EVERYTHING can be penetrated. In real life impenetrable means more along the lines of "can not be penetrated by 'normal' means".
Absolute statements usually only make sense in fictional settings as they often lead to logical errors/ inconsistencies. See "unstoppable force" or "immovable objects".
So my take is that "im..." or "un..." statements usually are not meant in a literal/absolute way but rather in a "not by conventional means" way.
